# Fitting table of contents into a single page

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I have a document that looks something like the following

[image]

**Is there any way to fit the entire TOC on a single page?**

I tried using `\vspace*`, alas that did nothing.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,
                 10pt, 
              b5paper, 
              openany]{amsbook}

\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,
            rmargin=25mm,
            tmargin=27mm,
            bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
\endgroup

\chapter{Lipsum}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{Lorem}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{this is halloween}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{halloween}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{halloween}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a font size a bit smaller, you could squeeze the toc on a single page. Another possibility to save some space would be to not include the toc as entry in the toc.

```
\documentclass[%pdflatex,
                 10pt, 
%              b5paper, 
              openany]{amsbook}

\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,
            rmargin=25mm,
            tmargin=27mm,
            bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \small
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
\endgroup

\chapter{Lipsum}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{Lorem}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{this is halloween}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{halloween}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\chapter{halloween}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\section{Eos} \section{Kronos} \section{Argos} \section{Genos} \section{Oroboros}

\end{document}
```